# Jquery - Scrolling to top

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I have a working jquery script that makes the page scroll to the bottom when a button is clicked. I am aiming to do this again, but instead of scrolling to the bottom, I would like it to scroll to the top of the page. Here is my code;

```
function scrolldown() { //Scroll to bottom
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1250);
};

function scrollup(){ //Scroll to top
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).top() }, 1250);
};
```

Please help me figure out what I need to do so that my script does as I want. Thanks!

Comment: Would this work: `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1250);` ??

Comment: It does, it also works without the html in the brackets.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1250);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4H4VY/

Comment: Thanks Moose! I shall keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

just use `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1250);` instead

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function scrollup(){ //Scroll to top
  $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1250);
};
```